# every prime in the form $3k+1$ can be written as the sum of a square and three times a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

i'm having trouble getting started

every prime in the form $3k+1$ can be written as the sum of a square and three times a square. verify this for all appropriate primes less than $100$.

hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $7$ is a prime of the form $3k+1$, since $7=3 \cdot 2 + 1$. Also, $7 = 2^2 + 3 \cdot 1^2$. Now, can you do the case for $13$?

Comment: $7 = 4 + 3, \; 13 = 1 + 12, \;  19 = 16 + 3$

Comment: What's the trouble? You don't know what a prime is? You don't know what $3k+1$ means? You don't know what a square is? You don't know what a sum is? You don't know what "verify" means? You don't know what "less than 100" means? Please, give us something to go on, otherwise, how can we help you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess the biggest thing is I am unsure of what type of proof I need to be using and how to prove for all numbers not just specific cases.. or if I only have to show a few cases. Its probably a really dumb thing to get stuck on but proof writing has never been a strength of mine.

Comment: The question, the way you have quoted it, says "verify this for all appropriate primes less than 100," so that's all you have to do. You are being told that it's true for every prime of the form $3k+1$, but you aren't being asked to prove that (which would be considerably harder to do).

Comment: @GerryMyerson OHHHH that makes so much more sense! I feel ridiculously stupid.

Comment: Don't. It takes time to learn how to interpret mathematical questions. They're in a foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

Proof for all $p$'s.

Recall Thue's result.

**Thue's Lemma:** Let $n>1$ be an integer, and $a$ be an integer coprime to $n$. Then, there exists $x,y$ with $0<x,y<\sqrt{n}$ so that, $x\equiv ay\pmod{n}$.

In some sense, $(a,n)=1$ can be represented as a fraction, both of whose numerator and denominator is at most $\sqrt{n}$. The proof is available in many places, and I omit herein.

---

Now, we will apply Thue's lemma. The key point is the well-known fact, if $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ a prime, then $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (that is, there exists an $x$ so that $x^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$). Now, let $0<x'<p$ be such a number, with $x'<p/2$ (note that, both $x'$ and $p-x'$ are so, and one of them is less than $p/2$, which, I assume to be $x'$ without any loss of generality).

Now, there is $0<a,b<\sqrt{p}$ with $a\equiv x'b\pmod{p}$. With this, $a^2+3b^2 \equiv b^2(x'^2+3)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. It now suffices to show $a^2+3b^2=p$. Clearly, $a^2+3b^2<4p$, hence the possibilities are $a^2+3b^2=p,2p,3p$. If $a^2+3b^2=3p$, then in modulo $3$ we see that $3\mid a$. Letting $a=3a_1$, we have $3a_1^2+b^2=p$, and therefore, $p$ can be represented in the desired manner.

If $a^2+3b^2=2p$, then we observe that $a$ and $b$ are of same parity. In both cases, you may see that $a^2+3b^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, while $4\nmid 2p$, a contradiction.

We are done.